# GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId returns empty String on first launch of App

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I´m refering to the[standard Android GCM Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html)

it seems like on first app launch the registration ID is set after the oncreate() Method has fired. How can I send the Registration ID from the GCMRegistrar.java back to the activity?

I call this in my MainActivity`s onCreate():

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    //provide RegID for the Class that can communicate with Javascript.


    Log.v(TAG, "regID: "+regId);
    if (regId.equals("")) {
      GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);

    } else {
      Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");

    }

    EDIT:
    //Call after .register also returns empty String on first App Launch
    String regId2 = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);// returns ""
```

It returns an empty String here on first start. In the log I see the registration ID is set later in the GCMRegistrar.java

```
static String setRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "REGISTRATION ID IN SET: "+regId);
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    String oldRegistrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    Log.v(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
    editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.commit();
    return oldRegistrationId;
}
```

This Method above is called in the GCMBaseIntentService.

If I run the App a second time, I can get the Reg. ID in the Mainactivity, how can I implement something like a callback function so I can access the Reg. ID in the MainActivity?

Comment: I also facing exact same issue...any luck here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes **GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this)** will return empty string if you are not registered with GCM.  Once you register then it will return actual registration ID. So that They used if() condition in their demo to check Whether this device is registered or not

Comment: hello Abhi, yes I was assuming this. When I try to call GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this); after GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID); it still returns an empty string so I assume the whole procedure is asynchronous. The question is how can I bring the regID from the GCMRegistrar to my activity in some callback function.

Comment: No.., Sure it will return regID once you register to GCM server. First check whether you can get register with GCM or not

Comment: I did, in the above code, the setRegistrationId is showing the regId in the Log, I just need this in my MainActivity.

Comment: @dan: I am facing same problem, did you get the solution for that, if so can you please share

Comment: not in particular, I ended up using a phonegap plugin for it: https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface say "GCMInterface" with an abstract method with an string argument, let your activity implement this interface i.e whatever you want to do with regId.  Pass the reference of your activity to your GCMIntentService. When onREgistered method of GCMIntentservice is called, call activity.method and pass regId as argument.

```
public interface GCMInterface {
    public void mOnRegistered(String id);
}

...

public class MyActivity implements GCMInterface {

    // implementation of GCMInterface interaface
    public void mOnRegistered(String id) {
        // do whatever you want to do with id
    }
}
...
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {


    GCMInterface interface;   // initialize it with your activity's context
    public GCMIntentService() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String regId) {
        // call mOnRegistered method with your activity's context like
        interface = (GCMInterface)context;
        if(interface != null) {
            interface.mOnRegistered(regId);
        }

    }

}
```

I hope you got my point.

Comment: Hi Khawar just one question how to pass the reference of the activity to the GCMIntentService? activitycontext doesnt know the method mOnRegistered. Thank you anyway.

Comment: when you call GCMRegistrar.register(context, PROJECT_ID), here context should be your activitie's context. you can simply call context.mOnRegistered(regId) in onRegistered(String regId) as my mistake, it is the same context as I referring in GCMRegistrar.register(context, PROJECT_ID).

Comment: I see so then I got the context of my MainActivity in the Registrar Class, but how to pass it to the IntentService from there?

Comment: I really appreciate your quick help, but context.mOnRegistered(regId) is undefined in onRegistered(String regId)

Comment: Sorry I took in wrong way. I have updated my answer. I hope it would work now.

Comment: hmm, now I got this: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.myapplicationandroid.GCMInterface

Comment: Hmm... You are right. I got the same exception. I though I would receive the same context as I passed to GCMRegistrar.register() method so that I can cast to interface. But I have found that it is not the case. So we have to implement this in another way.
Hmm... other way would be to create a broadcast receiver in your activity and broadcast an intent to that receiver in onRegistered method of GCMIntentService.

Comment: yep I have already tried that but it told me I have to unregister the receiver first, guess I will open another thread for the problem